# How to print multiple values from nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

One of my homework questions is to print on one line using a nested dictionary. How can I do that?

Comment: I have tried 
    print(employees[0]["employee_id"]
and
    print(employees[0, 1]["employee_id"]

Comment: You will need to loop throgh employees using for loop.

Comment: Now you have me confused. Are you asking how to print the employee_id on one line and on another line print their names formatted as lastname, firstname. ot print all employye_id on single line.

Answer (score 0):

```
for employee in employees:
    if employee["title"] == "Mr":
        print(employee["employee_id"])
        print(employee["lastname"], employee["firstname"])
```

Comment: Sorry, I have added in the code now there was two other employees but the question only asks for the male (first 2) employees

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multiple arguments of `print` to separate them by a space (can be changed with the `sep` argument):

```
print(employees[0]["employee_id"], employees[1]["employee_id"])
```

However, if you wanted to print out all of the ID's of the male employees, you have a few different options:

1. `for` loop:

   ```
   for employee in employees:
       if employee["title"] == "Mr":
           print(employee["employee_id"], end=" ")
   ```
2. Argument unpacking:

   ```
   male_employees = [employee["employee_id"] for employee in employees if employee["title"] == "Mr"]
   print(*male_employees)
   ```
3. `str.join`

   ```
   male_employees = [employee["employee_id"] for employee in employees if employee["title"] == "Mr"]
   print(" ".join(male_employees))
   ```

Especially for a homework question, the first option using a `for` loop is the most intuitive.

EDIT:

To print the names, you can use format strings:

```
for employee in employees:
    if employee["title"] == "Mr":
        print("{0}, {1}".format(employee["lastname"], employee["firstname"]), end=" ")
```

If you want to have a bit more fun, this is an option:

```
for employee in employees:
    if employee["title"] == "Mr":
        print("{lastname}, {firstname}".format(**employee), end=" ")
```

Comment: thank you so much!! for the loop, can I display both "lastname" and "firstname" on the same line?

Comment: @Tess What you said definitely sounds possible, but could you please edit your question with the desired output to output more clear?

Comment: oops yes sorry will do now!! sorry I'm very new to coding and python